# Validation before Insert query

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, validation

I am trying to prevent double bookings from occurring and I ended up choosing to do validation, however, it doesn't seem to be working correctly because each time I test it the record is inserted into the table.
Whenever I try to do the insert query am also getting this error message:

> Cannot access a disposed object
> Object name SQLite connection

Here is my code:

```
  Private Sub IbtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnCheckIn.Click
    Dim mssql As String = "SELECT rooms.roomnumber,roomtype.roomtypename,rooms.Ensuite,customers.fname, customers.lname, booking.arrivaldate,booking.departuredate FROM bookedrooms LEFT JOIN booking ON bookedrooms.brbookingID = booking.BookingID inner join rooms on rooms.roomID = BOOKEDROOMS.brRoomID INNER JOIN roomtype on roomtype.roomtypeid = rooms.rroomtypeid INNER JOIN customers on customers.customerid = booking.bcustomerid;"

    Try
        Dim SelectedValue As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmbBookingData.SelectedValue)
        Dim selectedRoom As String = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRoomNumber.Text)
        Dim Result = AddToRoom(SelectedValue, selectedRoom, "Taken")


        Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader
        reader = Validation(SelectedValue, txtDate1.Text, txtDate2.Text)
        If reader.Read() Then
            MsgBox("DoubleBooking")

        Else
            If Result > 0 Then
                MsgBox("New RECORD HAS BEEN ADDED!")
                Display(mssql, "bookedrooms")
            Else
                MsgBox("NO RECORD HAS BEEN ADDED!")
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

   Public Function Validation(brRoomID As Integer, ArrDate As String, DepDate As String)
    Dim reader As SQLiteDataReader
    Dim usql As String = "
        SELECT brRoomID, arrivaldate, departuredate FROM bookedrooms join booking on bookedrooms.brBookingID = booking.BookingID
        WHERE
       (brRoomID = @Room)
        AND (arrivaldate  <= @ArrDate ) AND (departuredate  >= @DepDate);"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand(usql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Room", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ArrDate", DbType.String).Value = ArrDate
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DepDate", DbType.String).Value = DepDate


        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()




    End Using
    Return reader

End Function
Public Function AddToRoom(BCustomerID As Integer, brRoomID As Integer, Status As String) As Integer
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim usql As String = "INSERT INTO bookedrooms(brBookingID,brRoomID,Status) VALUES (@brBookingID,@brRoomID,@Status)"
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand(usql, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@brBookingID", DbType.Int32).Value = BCustomerID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@brRoomID", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Status", DbType.String).Value = Status



        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

    End Using
    Return Result

End Function
```

Comment: A DbDataReader cannot survive if its connection is closed. The Using statement inside the Validation method will close the connection and you cannot use anymore the reader. It is useless to return it

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try

Comment: However I would check if the room is available before adding a record to the BookedRooms table

Answer (score 0):

Functions in vb.net must have a datatype and a Return statement.

The date fields appear to be Sqlite Text datatype. It needs to be stored as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS for you comparisons to work. I would suggest using a DateTimePicker rather than a TextBox for the date inputs. A user can enter anything in a TextBox and probably will not enter the correct format for a date.

I have separated the database code from the user interface code. No MessageBox or updating the UI in the data access code and no Sql statements in the UI code.

```
Private ConnectionString As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub IbtnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ibtnCheckIn.Click
    Dim Result As Integer
    Dim SelectedValue As Integer = CInt(cmbBookingData.SelectedValue)
    Dim selectedRoom As Integer = CInt(cmbRoomNumber.Text)
    Dim d1 = ValidateDates(txtDate1.Text)
    Dim d2 = ValidateDates(txtDate2.Text)
    If d1 = "Invalid" OrElse d2 = "Invalid" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid dates")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Try
        Result = InsertBooking(selectedRoom, d1, d2, SelectedValue, "Taken")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
    If Result < 1 Then
        MsgBox("DoubleBooking  NO RECORD HAS BEEN ADDED!")
    Else
        MsgBox("New RECORD HAS BEEN ADDED!")
        Try
            dt = GetBookedRooms()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function InsertBooking(brRoomID As Integer, ArrDate As String, DepDate As String,BCustomerID As Integer, Status As String) As Integer
    Dim ValidateSql As String = "SELECT brRoomID, arrivaldate, departuredate 
                                FROM bookedrooms 
                                Join booking on bookedrooms.brBookingID = booking.BookingID
                                WHERE (brRoomID = @Room)
                                AND (arrivaldate  <= @ArrDate ) 
                                AND (departuredate  >= @DepDate);"
    Dim InsertSql As String = "INSERT INTO bookedrooms(brBookingID,brRoomID,Status) 
                                VALUES (@brBookingID,@brRoomID,@Status)"
    Dim CommandSql = $"If Not Exists ({ValidateSql}) {InsertSql}"
    Dim Result As Integer
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString),
                cmd As New SQLiteCommand(CommandSql, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Room", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
            .Add("@ArrDate", DbType.String).Value = ArrDate
            .Add("@DepDate", DbType.String).Value = DepDate
            .Add("@brBookingID", DbType.Int32).Value = BCustomerID
            .Add("@brRoomID", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
            .Add("@Status", DbType.String).Value = Status
        End With
        con.Open()
        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return Result
End Function

Private Function GetBookedRooms() As DataTable
    Dim mssql As String = "SELECT rooms.roomnumber,roomtype.roomtypename,rooms.Ensuite,customers.fname, customers.lname, booking.arrivaldate,booking.departuredate 
                            FROM bookedrooms 
                            LEFT JOIN booking ON bookedrooms.brbookingID = booking.BookingID 
                            inner join rooms on rooms.roomID = BOOKEDROOMS.brRoomID 
                            INNER JOIN roomtype on roomtype.roomtypeid = rooms.rroomtypeid 
                            INNER JOIN customers on customers.customerid = booking.bcustomerid;"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString),
            cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mssql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Function ValidateDates(TextDate As String) As String
    Dim ValidDate As Date
    Dim StringDate As String
    If Date.TryParse(TextDate, ValidDate) Then
        StringDate = ValidDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.000")
    Else
        Return "Invalid"
    End If
    Return StringDate
End Function
```

**EDIT**

```
Private Function InsertBooking(brRoomID As Integer, ArrDate As String, DepDate As String, BCustomerID As Integer, Status As String) As Integer
    Dim ValidateSql As String = "SELECT brRoomID, arrivaldate, departuredate 
                            FROM bookedrooms 
                            Join booking on bookedrooms.brBookingID = booking.BookingID
                            WHERE (brRoomID = @Room)
                            AND (arrivaldate  <= @ArrDate ) 
                            AND (departuredate  >= @DepDate);"
    Dim InsertSql As String = $"INSERT INTO bookedrooms(brBookingID,brRoomID,Status) 
                            VALUES (@brBookingID,@brRoomID,@Status) Where Not Exists {ValidateSql}"
    Dim Result As Integer
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New SQLiteCommand(InsertSql, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Room", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
            .Add("@ArrDate", DbType.String).Value = ArrDate
            .Add("@DepDate", DbType.String).Value = DepDate
            .Add("@brBookingID", DbType.Int32).Value = BCustomerID
            .Add("@brRoomID", DbType.Int32).Value = brRoomID
            .Add("@Status", DbType.String).Value = Status
        End With
        con.Open()
        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    Return Result
End Function
```

Comment: Hi there, sorry but Sqlite doesn't support if functions `Dim CommandSql = $"If Not Exists ({ValidateSql}) {InsertSql}"` how could this be changed to work

Comment: @MiloszLaksa Please see the EDIT to the code. Sorry, moving to new computer and don't have SQLite installed yet.

Comment: Hi there @Mary syntax SQL logic error comes up near "Where"